# Función Watershed en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, opencv, scikit-learn

Me preguntaba si alguno supiera cómo implementar el algoritmo `Watershed` en Python. Estoy usando la función de skimage.segmentation y me da el siguiente resultado:

```
L = seg.watershed(f_g)
plt.imshow(L)
```

El resultado es el siguiente (no se aprecia nada)

[image: Watershed en Python]

En MATLAB, hago lo mismo:

```
L = watershed(f_g);
imshow(L);
```

Y ésta es la imagen (no se aprecia bien pero es la silueta de una llave):
[image: Watershed MATLAB]

¿Sabría alguno decirme cómo debo utilizar la función Watershed para que me saliera aproximadamente igual que en MATLAB? Estoy con mi TFG atascado en esta parte. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Sin entrar en la matemática detrás del algoritmo `watershed`. Es un algoritmo que se utiliza para segmentar las imagenes por profundidad, es decir, es bueno identificando cercania o lejanía en la foto.

Dicho esto, no tengo ni idea de lo que estás haciendo en MATLAB, pero el procesamiento de imagenes en cualquier lenguaje es **algo muy complejo**, tiene muchas operaciones matemáticas detrás y **no salen las cosas aplicando una función** y ya está (salvo que sean datos ya preparados). Mi respuesta es muy larga.

## 1. Pre-procesamiento de la imagen

Imaginemos que tenemos la siguiente foto y queremos identificar las monedas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Aplicamos el algoritmo `watershed` y ya está? Obviamente no, si hacemos eso saldrá una birria, porque **la propia moneda tiene fondo** (la cara, las letras, etc) al igual que una llave, la llave no es plana y tiene profundidad. Por lo tanto tenemos que pre-procesar la imagen antes.

Voy a centrarme en lo importante dejando código no referido a la pregunta sin explicar. **Con este código cargamos la imagen**, para que cualquiera pueda replicar el ejemplo.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import urllib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

req = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXy5T.jpg")
array = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
img_monedas = cv.imdecode(array, -1,)
img_monedas = cv.cvtColor(img_monedas, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img_monedas)
```

##### 1.1 Quitamos las caras de las monedas

Para esto podemos aplicar un "blur" o suavizado, este filtro es muy aplicado en redes sociales para quitarse las arrugas.

```
#Usamos un kernel size de 35, que es bastante grande, pero es lo que funciona
monedas_blur = cv.medianBlur(img_monedas, 35)
plt.imshow(monedas_blur)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

##### 1.2 Convertimos a escala de grises

Para buscar fondos y contornos por lo general siempre es mejor convertir a escala de grises.

**Salida:**

```
monedas_gris = cv.cvtColor(monedas_blur, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

##### 1.3 Aplicamos un umbral (threshold) para diferenciar lo que es el fondo

```
ret, monedas_umbral = cv.threshold(monedas_gris,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.imshow(monedas_umbral, cmap="gray")
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

##### 1.4 Guardamos el area de la imagen que estamos seguros de que es el fondo

A partir de aquí el proceso consiste en diferenciar el fondo de la imagen de las monedas, con `dilate` vamos a ver cual es el fondo de las monedas

Como podemos ver en la imagen anterior en blanco y negro, hay monedas que aparecen unidas, por lo tanto no estamos detectando bien los contornos de cada moneda, ni separando cada una de ella.

```
monedas_fondo = cv.dilate(monedas_umbral, kernel,iterations=3)
```

##### 1.5 Descubrimos cual es el área de las monedas que estamos seguros que NO es fondo

Como ya sabemos cual es el fondo de la imagen, ahora nos queda descubrir que parte NO es fondo y que parte no estamos seguros de que es (es decir las partes en las que las monedas se unen). Para ello aplicamos una transformación por distancia a cada centro de cada moneda, de tal forma que cuanto más alejado estes del centro, más probabilidad es de que ese área sea fondo, y no pertenezca a la moneda.

```
distancia_transform = cv.distanceTransform(monedas_fondo, cv.DIST_L2,5)
ret, no_fondo = cv.threshold(distancia_transform,0.7*distancia_transform.max(),255,0)
ret, no_fondo = cv.threshold(distancia_transform,0.7*distancia_transform.max(),255,0)
plt.imshow(distancia_transform, cmap="gray")
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

##### 1.6 Nos centramos en las regiones que son desconocidas

Es decir, en las reguiones que no tenemos claro si es fondo o es moneda, para ello **simplemente restamos una región a otra**

```
no_fondo = np.uint8(no_fondo)
region_desconocida = cv.subtract(monedas_fondo,no_fondo)
plt.imshow(region_desconocida, cmap="gray")[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][5]][5]
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las regiones que desconocemos si dichas áreas pertenecen a la moneda, o son el fondo de la imagen. **Por último** vamos a identificarlas marcandolas con unos y ceros, y habremos acabado con el pre-procesado.

```
ret, marcadores = cv.connectedComponents(no_fondo)
# Marcamos los fondos con 1
marcadores = marcadores+1
# Marcamos las regiones deconocidas con 0
marcadores[region_desconocida==255] = 0
```

### 2. Algoritmo Watershed

Una vez tenemos todo esto, estamos en condiciones de aplicar el algoritmo
`watershed` para que el resultado sea *decente*

```
monedas_watersheed = cv.watershed(monedas_blur, marcadores)
plt.imshow(monedas_watersheed)
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Genial, ya hemos aplicado el algoritmo, si queremos podemos traducir los segmentos identificados a la imagen original, para que quede más bonito:

```
#Por último le podemos dibujar el contorno para diferenciarlo claramente en la imagen inicial
contornos, jerarquía = cv.findContours(marcadores.copy(), cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i in range(len(contornos)):
    if jerarquía[0][i][3] == -1:
        cv.drawContours(img_monedas, contornos, i, (0, 0, 255), 10)

plt.imshow(img_monedas)
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es *bastante decente* podemos realizar un mejor preprocesado, o cambiar parámetros de funciones para mejorarlo aun más.

### Conclusiones

- Realizar un procesamiento de imagenes, es complejo, y cuando no se consiguen los resultados hay que aprender y pensar el por que.
- A mejor pre-procesado, mejor resultado, si el resultado no es bueno es que no estás tratando bien tus datos
- Aquí te he dejado varias funciones, todas ellas están explicadas en la [documentación oficial de OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), **te sugiero que te tomes tus días** en leer y entender cada apartado de esta respuesta para aplicarlo a tu problema
- Todo el procesamiento aquí explicado te servirá para tu caso de las llaves, excepto las distancias porque son distancias a un centroide, y las llaves no suelen ser redondas.